# Cannot compile typescript due to Module '"node:tls"' has no default export error

Tags: typescript

## Problem

I have a typescript based node.js project and when I compile my code, I get the following error. Namely I am trying to incorporate the cloud-sql-connector.

```
node_modules/@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector/dist/cjs/connector.d.ts:2:8 - error TS1192: Module '"node:tls"' has no default export.

2 import tls from 'node:tls';
```

My tsconfig.json is as following.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

In this specific situation, if I go to the file

`node_modules/@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector/dist/cjs/connector.d.ts:2:8` and manually modify this file so that.

```
import tls from 'node:tls'; // Fails
import * as tls from 'node:tls'; // Works
```

How can I make this to work without manually changing the file imported into node_modules?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You are missing `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` in your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

This option will allow you to import default exports from modules that do not have a default export.